# How do I use "while" in this situation

Tags: python, while-loop, python-3.3

```
# This program says hello and asks for my name, then repeats it.
print('Hello world!')
print('What is your name?')
myName = input()

while 
    print('It is nice to meet you, ' + myName)
```

---

My question is what do I put where while is?
I'm trying to learn how to use `while` loops but I do not know what to put after while to make it repeat your name forever.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to input one name and print it inifinetly, use:

```
print('Hello world!')
print('What is your name?')
myName = input()

while True:
    print('It is nice to meet you, ' + myName)
```

If you want to input a name, print it, then input another and so on, use:

```
print('Hello world!')
while True:
    print('It is nice to meet you, ' + input('What is your name? '))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use any condition that will always evaluate to `True`. The most obvious (and thus preferable) way is

```
while True:
    print('It is nice to meet you, ' + myName)
```

Also note that you don't need to use string concatenation with `print()`:

```
print('It is nice to meet you,', myName)
```